# Isolating product pages in Google Analytics with regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm setting up Content Groups in Google Analytics from the following logic:

- Front page
- Section pages
- Category pages
- Subcategory pages
- Product pages
- Checkout flow

I've done the top levels like this: ^/sektion-1/kategori-1$|^/sektion-2/kategori2$.

But I don't know about the product pages. there is nothing in the page title or the URL the identifies the product pages. Product pages are always level 3 in the URL, but they are not the ONLY pages on level 3.

So, how can I isolate those without having to include regex for each and every one of them? (there are 10.000+ product pages)

Comment: English only please

Comment: "I'm about to put Content Groups in Google Analytics by a division called" as per Google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are many product pages without matching URL. I would recommend setting up content group by tracking code.

Add this code to all product pages ga('set', 'contentGroup1', ‘Product Pages');

This method is simple and more fool proof then regex.

hope this help

Analytics ML